# Django - how do I select all checkboxes, without changes to object model?

Tags: python, django

I'm generating a series of checkboxes populated from a DB. How best should I think about doing a check-all? I.e. not change the object model, but be able in the template to click a box and select all options.

From forms, I'm creating checkboxes with:

```
MyGender = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gender.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

and in the view:

```
form = MyPreferencesForm(request.POST)
```

and to display:

```
return render(request, "mypreferences.html",{'form': form})
```

Could one solution that doesn't involve JS be to have an extra DB field, and before saving perform a check to see if select all has been opted for and then populate the saved object with every option. Of course visually none of the other boxes would change so this isn't great from a UI perspective but it does mean no JS.

How could do select all as robustly as possible? With JS or without?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Can you post the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: "be able in the template to click a box and select all options" - it seems you are talking about something happening on the client side. If that's correct then this is not something you would do in Django, but rather in JavaScript.

Comment: OK. I wasn't sure whether Django could create some JavaScript to do this. Used to .net So is there a smart way to do this with JavaScript and marry the two together?